# Como poner un video sobre una imagen('foto')

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quisiera poner el video sobre la foto para que el usuario pueda visualizarse en el mismo cuadro

```js
var constraints;
var imageCapture;
var mediaStream;

var grabFrameButton = document.querySelector('button#grabFrame');

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var img = document.querySelector('img');
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');
var zoomInput = document.querySelector('input#zoom');

grabFrameButton.onclick = grabFrame;
videoSelect.onchange = getStream;
zoomInput.oninput = setZoom;

navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(gotDevices)
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('enumerateDevices() error: ', error);
  })
  .then(getStream);

function gotDevices(deviceInfos) {
  for (var i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
    var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
    console.log('Found media input or output device: ', deviceInfo);
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
    if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
      option.text = deviceInfo.label || 'Camera ' + (videoSelect.length + 1);
      videoSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
}

function getStream() {
  if (mediaStream) {
    mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      track.stop();
    });
  }
  var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
  constraints = {
    video: {
      deviceId: videoSource ? {
        exact: videoSource
      } : undefined
    }
  };
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(gotStream)
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('getUserMedia error: ', error);
    });
}

// Display the stream from the currently selected camera source, and then
// create an ImageCapture object, using the video from the stream.
function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log('getUserMedia() got stream: ', stream);
  mediaStream = stream;
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.classList.remove('hidden');
  imageCapture = new ImageCapture(stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
  getCapabilities();
}

function getCapabilities() {
  imageCapture.getPhotoCapabilities().then(function(capabilities) {
    console.log('Camera capabilities:', capabilities);
    if (capabilities.zoom.max > 0) {
      zoomInput.min = capabilities.zoom.min;
      zoomInput.max = capabilities.zoom.max;
      zoomInput.value = capabilities.zoom.current;
      zoomInput.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('getCapabilities() error: ', error);
  });
}

function grabFrame() {
  imageCapture.grabFrame().then(function(imageBitmap) {
    console.log('Grabbed frame:', imageBitmap);
    canvas.width = imageBitmap.width;
    canvas.height = imageBitmap.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
    canvas.classList.remove('hidden');
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('grabFrame() error: ', error);
  });
}

function setZoom() {
  imageCapture.setOptions({
    zoom: zoomInput.value
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

video {
  width: 159px;
  height: 100px;
}

canvas {
  width: 259px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <button id="grabFrame">Tomar Foto</button>
  <div class="select">
    <label for="videoSource">Resolucion de la imagen: </label>
    <select id="videoSource"></select>
  </div>
  <input class="hidden" id="zoom" type="range" step="20">

  <video autoplay class="hidden"></video>
  <img>
  <canvas class="hidden"></canvas>
</div>
```

Asi es como esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como deberia verse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

lo que podría hacer es agregar una función a tu *script* para que pocisione el video sobre la imagen.

```
 function montar() {
    video.style.position="relative";
    video.style.width="159px";
    video.style.height="100px";
    video.style.top="-100px";
    video.style.left="155px";
 }
```

Agrega ese método y luego mándalo a llamar en tu método `grabFrame()`

```
function grabFrame() {
    imageCapture.grabFrame().then(function(imageBitmap) {
    console.log('Grabbed frame:', imageBitmap);
    canvas.width = imageBitmap.width;
    canvas.height = imageBitmap.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);  

    montar();

    canvas.classList.remove('hidden');
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log('grabFrame() error: ', error);
  });
}
```

Intenta aplicarlo.